# How to check the version of maven running in NetBeans 12.2?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

How can I view (and potentially change) the version of [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) running on my NetBeans 12.2 IDE?

Answer (score 2):

In the `Options` window, select the `Java` tab and `Maven` sub-tab. By default, the bundled version is shown: 3.6.3. Click the `Maven Home` dropdown to select a different version [installed](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) elsewhere on your system.

[image]

The bundled executable is stored in the Apache NetBeans installation folder under `java/maven/bin/mvn`; it can be run from the command line, for example:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /Applications/NetBeans/Apache NetBeans 12.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/java/maven
Java version: 11.0.10, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.10.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
```